# Point is close to the diagonal

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I would like to calculate if the point is near a diagonal of rectangle.
The rectangle is representing as two points (min and max). Now I have third point and I would like to check if is near the diagonal.

```
if (minBound < pointVector2 && pointVector2 < maxBound) {
    CheckIfIsNearTheDiagonal(50, true);
}
```

`minBound` and `maxBound` are the border points (`Vector2`)

I'd like to check how far the point `pointVector2` is from (specific) diagonal. The distance compare with the argument maxDistance and return if is in the range around the diagonal.

```
bool CheckIfIsNearTheDiagonal(float maxDistance, bool isLeftDownToRightUp ){
   // Somehow count distance
   return distance < maxDistance
}
```

Is there any simple way or I must calculate general form of equation of a line and a distance between the point and the line?

Comment: Seems like you have already described the simple way.

Comment: Ok if it is the simplest way. =(

Comment: Here's another way:  Picture a triangle from a corner of the rectangle to the point in question to the point along the diagonal to which the distance is being measured.  You know the length of one side (the hypotenuse of the triangle, which is the line from the corner to the point in question).  Use dot product to get the length of the line from the corner to the other point on the diagonal.  Now that you have two sides of the triangle, use Pythagorean Theorem to get the length of the 3rd side.  This final length is the distance you are looking for.

Comment: System.Math.Sqrt is so expensive (the function is called on every frame update) so I'll use the first way (just one Sqrt in a constructor and noone in the frame update). But I am very grateful for the second option.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to use Pythagorean Theorem in the second option.  Once you know the lengths of the two sides that originate from the corner of the rectangle, you can just subtract the vector along the diagonal from the hypotenuse vector, giving you the distance vector. You still need square root to get the magnitude of the distance vector.

Comment: In school we called that hessian normal distance (formula see also answer from Fransco)

Answer (score 2):

This gives you the distance from Point p0 and the line passing in p1 and p2:

```
    public double Distance(Point p1, Point p2, Point p0)
    {
        double m = (p2.Y - p1.Y) / (p2.X - p1.X);
        double q = (p1.Y * p2.X - p2.Y * p1.X) / (p2.X - p1.X);
        return Math.Abs((p0.Y - m * p0.X - q) / Math.Sqrt(1 + m * m));
    }
```